# how swap an image to another in a slider with a function that compare the browser window's size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have the html that is like this:

```
<body>

 <ul class="slider">
  <li class="slide"><img src="img/Slide-01 web.png" alt="Slide 1" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="img/Slide-02-web.jpg" alt="Slide 2" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="img/Slide-03-web.jpg" alt="Slide 3" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="img/Slide-04-web.jpg" alt="Slide 4" /></li>

</ul>
```

and I have to set a really easy function, like this but surely this is wrong:

```
<script>
        $(window).width(function(){
            var window = $(this).width();
            if(window < 650) {
                $(".slide img:nth-child(1)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-01.jpg");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(2)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-02.jpg");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(3)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-03.jpg");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(4)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-04.jpg");
            }
            if(window >= 650) {
                $(".slide img:nth-child(1)").attr("src","img/Slide-01 web.png");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(2)").attr("src","img/Slide-02-web.png");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(3)").attr("src","img/Slide-03-web.png");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(4)").attr("src","img/Slide-04-web.png");
            }

        });
    </script>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What part of it is not working? are you getting any errors? specfic to any browsers? what have you tried already?

Comment: it don't swap any image of the slider when i see it in a browser window under 650px of width.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your `nth-child` in a wrong way try it like this change the `width` of the body to see the change. Use `nth-child` like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zhLm7xm/)

```
 $(".slide:nth-child(1) img").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/305");
```

```js
$(window).width(function(){
            var win = $('body').width();
            if(win < 650) {
                $(".slide:nth-child(1) img").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/305");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(2)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/306");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(3)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/307");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(4)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/308");
            }
            if(win >= 650) {
                $(".slide:nth-child(1) img").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/309");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(2)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/310");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(3)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/311");
                $(".slide img:nth-child(4)").attr("src","http://placekitten.com/300/312");
            }

        });
```

```css
body{
    width:600px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <ul class="slider">
  <li class="slide"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" alt="Slide 1" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/302" alt="Slide 2" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/303" alt="Slide 3" /></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/304" alt="Slide 4" /></li>

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: it work but  i need that it do this not with body width but with window width, like @media screen and (min-width: 440px) and (max-width: 640px) for example

Comment: @SergioVento You can either use `resize()` function or use `$(window).width()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign width to `window` variable. Because it's a reserved word. Try using some other variable name.

Other issue with your code is that you are using wrong selector. `:nth-child` can be used to selected a child, not the nth numbered element. You need to use `$(".slide img:nth(1)")` for second element.

Correct example :

```
<script>
    $(window).width(function(){
        var windowWidth = $(this).width();
        if(windowWidth < 650) {
            $(".slide img:nth(1)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-01.jpg");
            $(".slide img:nth(2)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-02.jpg");
            $(".slide img:nth(3)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-03.jpg");
            $(".slide img:nth(4)").attr("src","img/Slide-Wella-Landing-Collezioni-2015-Mobile-Web-04.jpg");
        }
        if(windowWidth >= 650) {
            $(".slide img:nth(1)").attr("src","img/Slide-01 web.png");
            $(".slide img:nth(2)").attr("src","img/Slide-02-web.png");
            $(".slide img:nth(3)").attr("src","img/Slide-03-web.png");
            $(".slide img:nth(4)").attr("src","img/Slide-04-web.png");
        }

    });
</script>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hv4hbxb/)